# View creating error. Failed: Warning: Execution is completed with a warning

Tags: sql, oracle

I apologize in advance for the long code. When creating a view, an error occurs when adding the "rating3" case (highlighted with several line breaks). Everything works without it. Otherwise, the script is fully working. What could be the reason for the error?
Oracle throws an error in this line: ***CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "EDUC"."PF_RATING" ("YEAR", "SEMESTER", "PERSONID", "UNITID", "WORKID", "EDITED_ITEMS_1", "EDITED_ITEMS_2", "ITEMS0", "ITEMS1", "ITEMS2", "RATING0", "RATING1", "RATING2","RATING3", "REJECT1", "REJECT2")***

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "EDUC"."PF_RATING" ("YEAR", "SEMESTER", "PERSONID", "UNITID", "WORKID", "EDITED_ITEMS_1", "EDITED_ITEMS_2", "ITEMS0", "ITEMS1", "ITEMS2", "RATING0", "RATING1", "RATING2","RATING3", "REJECT1", "REJECT2") AS 
  SELECT r.YEAR, st.semester, r.personid, u.unitid, w.workid,
    SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN ( a1.affirm1date                       IS NULL
      AND NVL(A1.ERRORDATE,to_date('1.01.1000'))   < A1.POSTEDDATE
      AND NVL(A1.REJECT1DATE,to_date('1.01.1000')) < A1.POSTEDDATE
      AND NVL(A1.REJECT2DATE,to_date('1.01.1000')) < A1.POSTEDDATE)
      THEN NVL(r.item,0)
      ELSE 0
    END) edited_items_1,
    SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN ( ( a1.affirm2date                     IS NULL
      OR NVL(A1.affirm2date,to_date('1.01.1000'))  < A1.POSTEDDATE)
      AND a1.affirm1date                          IS NULL
      AND NVL(A1.ERRORDATE,to_date('1.01.1000'))   < A1.POSTEDDATE
      AND NVL(A1.REJECT2DATE,to_date('1.01.1000')) < A1.POSTEDDATE
      AND NVL(A1.REJECT1DATE,to_date('1.01.1000')) < A1.POSTEDDATE )
      THEN NVL(r.item,0)
      ELSE 0
    END) edited_items_2,
    SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN (a1.posteddate IS NOT NULL AND (a1.posteddate>a1.errordate OR a1.errordate IS NULL))
      THEN NVL(r.item,0)
      ELSE 0
    END) items0,
    SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN (a1.affirm2date IS NOT NULL AND ( a1.affirm2date>a1.reject2date OR a1.reject2date IS NULL ))
      THEN NVL(r.item,0)
      ELSE 0
    END) items1,
    SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN (a1.affirm1date IS NOT NULL AND ( a1.affirm1date >a1.reject1date OR a1.reject1date IS NULL))
      THEN NVL(r.item,0)
      ELSE 0
    END) items2,
    SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN (a1.posteddate IS NOT NULL AND ( a1.errordate IS NULL OR a1.posteddate >a1.errordate)) 
      THEN DECODE(p.items,0,1,r.item/p.items)*( case when (r.year*10+st.semester <=20190) then p.price
                                                     when (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and u.unitid!=15) then p.price
                                                     when (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and u.unitid=15 and   nvl(ed.is_preparation,0)=0) then p.price 
                                                     when (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and u.unitid=15 and   nvl(ed.is_preparation,0)=1) then 1
                                                     end )
                                                                        
                                                                        * (case when (r.year*10+st.semester <=20190) then 1
                                                            when  (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and u.unitid!=13 and u.unitid!=34 and u.unitid!=15  ) then 1
                                                            when  (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and (u.unitid=13 or u.unitid=34) and nvl(ed.games,0)=0) then 1
                                                            when (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and (u.unitid=13 or u.unitid=34) and nvl(ed.games,0)>0 and evp.reward_code in(9,11)) then 1
                                                            when (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and (u.unitid=13 or u.unitid=34) and nvl(ed.games,0)>0 and evp.reward_code in(5,6,7,8)) then nvl(evp.student_games,0)/ed.games    
                                                            when (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and u.unitid=15  and nvl(ed.is_preparation,0)=0)  then 1
                                                            when (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and u.unitid=15  and nvl(ed.is_preparation,0)=1)  then 0.1
                                                             else 1 
                                                            end
                                                        )
      ELSE 0  
    END) rating0,
    SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN (a1.affirm2date IS NOT NULL
      AND ( a1.reject2date IS NULL
      OR a1.affirm2date     >a1.reject2date ) )  
      THEN DECODE(p.items,0,1,r.item/p.items)*( case when (r.year*10+st.semester <=20190) then p.price
                                                     when (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and u.unitid!=15) then p.price
                                                     when (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and u.unitid=15 and   nvl(ed.is_preparation,0)=0) then p.price 
                                                     when (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and u.unitid=15 and   nvl(ed.is_preparation,0)=1) then 1
                                                     end )
                                                     *
                                                     (case when (r.year*10+st.semester <=20190) then 1
                                                            when  (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and u.unitid!=13 and u.unitid!=34 and u.unitid!=15  ) then 1
                                                            when  (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and (u.unitid=13 or u.unitid=34) and nvl(ed.games,0)=0) then 1
                                                            when (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and (u.unitid=13 or u.unitid=34) and nvl(ed.games,0)>0 and evp.reward_code in(9,11)) then 1
                                                            when (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and (u.unitid=13 or u.unitid=34) and nvl(ed.games,0)>0 and evp.reward_code in(5,6,7,8)) then nvl(evp.student_games,0)/ed.games    
                                                            when (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and u.unitid=15  and nvl(ed.is_preparation,0)=0)  then 1
                                                            when (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and u.unitid=15  and nvl(ed.is_preparation,0)=1)  then 0.1
                                                            else 1
                                                            end
                                                        )
      ELSE 0
    END) rating1,
    SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN (U.UNITID = 17 OR U.UNITID=18 OR U.UNITID=22) AND (a1.posteddate IS NOT NULL AND (a1.errordate IS NULL OR a1.posteddate>a1.errordate))
      THEN DECODE(P.ITEMS,0,1,R.ITEM/P.ITEMS)*P.PRICE
      WHEN (a1.affirm1date IS NOT NULL AND ( a1.reject1date IS NULL OR a1.affirm1date>a1.reject1date)) 
      THEN DECODE(p.items,0,1,r.item/p.items)*( case when (r.year*10+st.semester <=20190) then p.price
                                                     when (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and u.unitid!=15) then p.price
                                                     when (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and u.unitid=15 and   nvl(ed.is_preparation,0)=0) then p.price 
                                                     when (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and u.unitid=15 and   nvl(ed.is_preparation,0)=1) then 1
                                                     end )
                                                     *
                                                       (case when (r.year*10+st.semester <=20190) then 1
                                                            when  (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and u.unitid!=13 and u.unitid!=34 and u.unitid!=15  ) then 1
                                                            when  (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and (u.unitid=13 or u.unitid=34) and nvl(ed.games,0)=0) then 1
                                                            when (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and (u.unitid=13 or u.unitid=34) and nvl(ed.games,0)>0 and evp.reward_code in(9,11)) then 1
                                                            when (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and (u.unitid=13 or u.unitid=34) and nvl(ed.games,0)>0 and evp.reward_code in(5,6,7,8)) then nvl(evp.student_games,0)/ed.games    
                                                            when (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and u.unitid=15  and nvl(ed.is_preparation,0)=0)  then 1
                                                            when (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and u.unitid=15  and nvl(ed.is_preparation,0)=1)  then 0.1
                                                            else 1
                                                            end
                                                        )
      ELSE 0
    END) rating2,     
    SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN (U.UNITID = 17 OR U.UNITID=18 OR U.UNITID=22) AND (a1.posteddate IS NOT NULL AND (a1.errordate IS NULL OR a1.posteddate>a1.errordate))
      THEN DECODE(P.ITEMS,0,1,R.ITEM/P.ITEMS)*P.PRICE
      WHEN (a1.affirm1date IS NOT NULL AND ( a1.reject1date IS NULL OR a1.affirm1date>a1.reject1date)) 
      THEN DECODE(p.items,0,1,r.item/p.items)*( case when (r.year*10+st.semester <=20190) then p.price
                                                     when (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and u.unitid!=15) then p.price
                                                     when (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and u.unitid=15 and   nvl(ed.is_preparation,0)=0) then p.price 
                                                     when (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and u.unitid=15 and   nvl(ed.is_preparation,0)=1) then 1
                                                     end )
                                                     *
                                                       (case when (r.year*10+st.semester <=20190) then 1
                                                            when  (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and u.unitid!=13 and u.unitid!=34 and u.unitid!=15  ) then 1
                                                            when  (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and (u.unitid=13 or u.unitid=34) and nvl(ed.games,0)=0) then 1
                                                            when (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and (u.unitid=13 or u.unitid=34) and nvl(ed.games,0)>0 and evp.reward_code in(9,11)) then 1
                                                            when (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and (u.unitid=13 or u.unitid=34) and nvl(ed.games,0)>0 and evp.reward_code in(5,6,7,8)) then nvl(evp.student_games,0)  
                                                            when (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and u.unitid=15  and nvl(ed.is_preparation,0)=0)  then 1
                                                            when (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and u.unitid=15  and nvl(ed.is_preparation,0)=1)  then 0.1
                                                            else 1
                                                            end
                                                        )
      ELSE 0
    END) rating3,
    SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN (a1.reject1date IS NOT NULL AND (a1.affirm1date IS NULL OR a1.affirm1date<a1.reject1date) AND a1.posteddate<a1.reject1date AND (a1.errordate IS NULL OR a1.errordate < a1.reject1date))   
      THEN DECODE(p.items,0,1,r.item/p.items)*( case when (r.year*10+st.semester <=20190) then p.price
                                                     when (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and u.unitid!=15) then p.price
                                                     when (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and u.unitid=15 and   nvl(ed.is_preparation,0)=0) then p.price 
                                                     when (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and u.unitid=15 and   nvl(ed.is_preparation,0)=1) then 1
                                                     end )
                                                     *
                                                       (case when (r.year*10+st.semester <=20190) then 1
                                                            when  (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and u.unitid!=13 and u.unitid!=34 and u.unitid!=15  ) then 1
                                                            when  (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and (u.unitid=13 or u.unitid=34) and nvl(ed.games,0)=0) then 1
                                                            when (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and (u.unitid=13 or u.unitid=34) and nvl(ed.games,0)>0 and evp.reward_code in(9,11)) then 1
                                                            when (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and (u.unitid=13 or u.unitid=34) and nvl(ed.games,0)>0 and evp.reward_code in(5,6,7,8)) then nvl(evp.student_games,0)/ed.games    
                                                            when (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and u.unitid=15  and nvl(ed.is_preparation,0)=0)  then 1
                                                            when (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and u.unitid=15  and nvl(ed.is_preparation,0)=1)  then 0.1
                                                            else 1
                                                            end
                                                        )
      ELSE 0
    END) REJECT1,
    SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN (a1.reject2date IS NOT NULL AND (A1.AFFIRM2DATE IS NULL OR A1.AFFIRM2DATE < A1.REJECT2DATE) AND a1.posteddate < a1.reject2date AND (a1.errordate IS NULL OR a1.errordate < a1.reject2date))   
      THEN DECODE(p.items,0,1,r.item/p.items)*( case when (r.year*10+st.semester <=20190) then p.price
                                                     when (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and u.unitid!=15) then p.price
                                                     when (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and u.unitid=15 and   nvl(ed.is_preparation,0)=0) then p.price 
                                                     when (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and u.unitid=15 and   nvl(ed.is_preparation,0)=1) then 1
                                                     end )
                                                     *
                                                       (case when (r.year*10+st.semester <=20190) then 1
                                                            when  (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and u.unitid!=13 and u.unitid!=34 and u.unitid!=15  ) then 1
                                                            when  (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and (u.unitid=13 or u.unitid=34) and nvl(ed.games,0)=0) then 1
                                                            when (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and (u.unitid=13 or u.unitid=34) and nvl(ed.games,0)>0 and evp.reward_code in(9,11)) then 1
                                                            when (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and (u.unitid=13 or u.unitid=34) and nvl(ed.games,0)>0 and evp.reward_code in(5,6,7,8)) then nvl(evp.student_games,0)/ed.games    
                                                            when (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and u.unitid=15  and nvl(ed.is_preparation,0)=0)  then 1
                                                            when (r.year*10+st.semester >20190 and u.unitid=15  and nvl(ed.is_preparation,0)=1)  then 0.1
                                                            else 1
                                                            end
                                                        )
      ELSE 0
    END) reject2
  FROM pf_rating_items r
  JOIN sw_works w ON r.workid=w.workid
  JOIN sw_units u ON w.unitid=u.unitid
  JOIN rb_semester_terms st ON r.item_date BETWEEN ST.BEGIN_STUDENT_RATING_DATE AND ST.END_STUDENT_RATING_DATE
  JOIN sw_workprices p  ON r.workid   =p.workid  AND r.year    =p.year  AND p.semester=st.semester
  LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT table_name, row_id, MAX(s_date) s_date
    FROM sw_affirmation
    GROUP BY table_name, row_id
    ) a  ON r.table_name=a.table_name AND r.row_id=A.row_id
  JOIN sw_terms swt ON SWT.year=R.year  AND swt.semester=st.semester
  JOIN SW_AFFIRMATION_LASTSTATUS A1 ON A1.TABLE_NAME=R.TABLE_NAME AND A1.ROW_ID=R.ROW_ID
  left JOIN pf_events_persons evp ON EVP.ID=R.ROW_ID AND R.PERSONID=EVP.PERSONID
  LEFT JOIN pf_events_DIRECTORY ed ON ed.eventid=evp.eventid
  WHERE u.isteacher  = 0
         AND SWT.ISTEACHER =0
  GROUP BY R.year, ST.SEMESTER, R.PERSONID, U.UNITID, W.WORKID
  UNION ALL   
  SELECT ST.YEAR, ST.SEMESTER, SR.PERSONID, 14, 482, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, sum(DECODE(P.ITEMS,0,1,1/P.ITEMS)*P.PRICE), 
            sum(DECODE(P.ITEMS,0,1,1/P.ITEMS)*P.PRICE), sum(DECODE(P.ITEMS,0,1,1/P.ITEMS)*P.PRICE), 0, 0
  FROM DOP_LESSONS L 
  left JOIN DOP_THEME T ON T.THEMEID = L.THEMEID 
  JOIN DOP_JOURNAL J ON J.LESSONID = L.LESSONID 
  JOIN FC_STUDENTRECORDS SR ON SR.RECORDID = J.STUDENTID  and sr.deleted=0 
  JOIN RB_SEMESTER_TERMS ST ON L.L_DATE BETWEEN ST.BEGIN_STUDENT_RATING_DATE AND ST.END_STUDENT_RATING_DATE
  JOIN SW_WORKPRICES P ON P.WORKID= 482  AND P.YEAR = ST.YEAR AND P.SEMESTER=ST.SEMESTER
  WHERE J.PRESENCE = 1 AND STUDENTRATINGYEAR(L.L_DATE) > 2016
  AND (EXISTS (SELECT  1 FROM    dop_application_form  WHERE   LESSONID  = L.LESSONID AND STUDENTID=SR.RECORDID) or l.ACTIVITYTYPE in (3,4))
  GROUP by ST.YEAR, ST.SEMESTER, SR.PERSONID
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ST.YEAR, ST.SEMESTER, SR.PERSONID, 14, 483, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, sum(J.BALL), sum(J.BALL), sum(J.BALL), 0, 0
  FROM DOP_LESSONS L 
  left JOIN DOP_THEME T ON T.THEMEID = L.THEMEID 
  JOIN DOP_JOURNAL J ON J.LESSONID = L.LESSONID 
  JOIN FC_STUDENTRECORDS SR ON SR.RECORDID = J.STUDENTID 
  JOIN RB_SEMESTER_TERMS ST ON L.L_DATE BETWEEN ST.BEGIN_STUDENT_RATING_DATE AND ST.END_STUDENT_RATING_DATE
  WHERE J.BALL > 0 AND STUDENTRATINGYEAR(L.L_DATE) > 2016
  AND (EXISTS (SELECT  1 FROM    dop_application_form  WHERE   LESSONID  = L.LESSONID AND STUDENTID=SR.RECORDID) or l.ACTIVITYTYPE in (3,4))
  GROUP BY ST.YEAR, ST.SEMESTER, SR.PERSONID
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ST.YEAR, ST.SEMESTER, SR.PERSONID, 14, 483, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, sum(TJ.TASK_BALL), sum(TJ.TASK_BALL), sum(TJ.TASK_BALL), 0, 0
  FROM DOP_LESSONS L 
  left JOIN DOP_THEME T ON T.THEMEID = L.THEMEID 
  JOIN DOP_LESSONS_TASKS LT ON LT.LESSONID = L.LESSONID 
  JOIN DOP_TASK_JOURNAL TJ ON TJ.TASKID = LT.TASKID  
  JOIN FC_STUDENTRECORDS SR ON SR.RECORDID = TJ.STUDENTID  
  JOIN RB_SEMESTER_TERMS ST ON L.L_DATE BETWEEN ST.BEGIN_STUDENT_RATING_DATE AND ST.END_STUDENT_RATING_DATE
  WHERE TJ.TASK_BALL > 0 AND STUDENTRATINGYEAR(L.L_DATE) > 2017 
  AND (EXISTS (SELECT  1 FROM    dop_application_form  WHERE   LESSONID  = L.LESSONID AND STUDENTID=SR.RECORDID) or l.ACTIVITYTYPE in (3,4))
  GROUP BY ST.YEAR, ST.SEMESTER, SR.PERSONID
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ST.YEAR, ST.SEMESTER, SR.PERSONID, 14, 279, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, sum(round(floor((D.END_TIME-D.BEGIN_TIME)/60)+mod((D.END_TIME-D.BEGIN_TIME),60)/60)*P.PRICE), 
            sum(round(floor((D.END_TIME-D.BEGIN_TIME)/60)+mod((D.END_TIME-D.BEGIN_TIME),60)/60)*P.PRICE), sum(round(floor((D.END_TIME-D.BEGIN_TIME)/60)+mod((D.END_TIME-D.BEGIN_TIME),60)/60)*P.PRICE), 0, 0
  FROM DOP_DUTY D 
  JOIN FC_STUDENTRECORDS SR ON SR.RECORDID = D.STUDENTID 
  JOIN RB_SEMESTER_TERMS ST ON D.DUTY_DATE BETWEEN ST.BEGIN_STUDENT_RATING_DATE AND ST.END_STUDENT_RATING_DATE
  JOIN SW_WORKPRICES P ON P.WORKID= 279 AND P.YEAR = ST.YEAR AND P.SEMESTER=ST.SEMESTER
  WHERE ST.YEAR*10+ST.SEMESTER > 20170 AND NVL(D.PRESENCE,0) = 1
  GROUP BY ST.YEAR, ST.SEMESTER, SR.PERSONID
  UNION ALL
  select ST.YEAR, ST.SEMESTER, SR.PERSONID, 14, 1886, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, sum(DECODE(P.ITEMS,0,1,1/P.ITEMS)*P.PRICE), 
            sum(DECODE(P.ITEMS,0,1,1/P.ITEMS)*P.PRICE), sum(DECODE(P.ITEMS,0,1,1/P.ITEMS)*P.PRICE), 0, 0
  from (select ds.documentid, max(ds.status_date) last_status_date   
            from dop_document_status ds 
        group by ds.documentid 
           ) ds
  join dop_document_status s on s.DOCUMENTID=ds.documentid and s.STATUS_DATE=ds.last_status_date
  join dop_documents d on d.documentid=ds.documentid
  JOIN FC_STUDENTRECORDS SR ON SR.RECORDID = D.STUDENTID
  JOIN RB_SEMESTER_TERMS ST ON d.end_date BETWEEN ST.BEGIN_STUDENT_RATING_DATE AND ST.END_STUDENT_RATING_DATE
  JOIN SW_WORKPRICES P ON P.WORKID= 1886 AND P.YEAR = ST.YEAR AND P.SEMESTER=ST.SEMESTER
  where s.STATUS_CODE=3
  GROUP by ST.YEAR, ST.SEMESTER, SR.PERSONID
  UNION ALL
  /*документы юр.клиники*/
  select ST.YEAR, ST.SEMESTER, SR.PERSONID, 14, decode(d.DOC_TYPE,1,1944,2,1945,3,1946,4,1947,5,1948,6,1949,7,1950,8,1951,9,1952,10,1953,11,1954,12,1955,13,1956,14,1957,15,1958,16,1959,17,1960) workid, 
      0, 0, 1, 1, 1, sum(DECODE(P.ITEMS,0,1,1/P.ITEMS)*P.PRICE), 
            sum(DECODE(P.ITEMS,0,1,1/P.ITEMS)*P.PRICE), sum(DECODE(P.ITEMS,0,1,1/P.ITEMS)*P.PRICE), 0, 0
  from (select ds.documentid, max(ds.status_date) last_status_date   
            from dop_document_status_new ds 
        group by ds.documentid 
           ) ds
  join dop_document_status_new s on s.DOCUMENTID=ds.documentid and s.STATUS_DATE=ds.last_status_date
  join dop_documents_new d on d.documentid=ds.documentid
  join ad_users u on u.username=d.username and u.ISSTUDENT=1
  left JOIN FC_STUDENTRECORDS SR ON SR.RECORDID = U.STUDENTID 
  left JOIN RB_SEMESTER_TERMS ST ON ds.last_status_date BETWEEN ST.BEGIN_STUDENT_RATING_DATE AND ST.END_STUDENT_RATING_DATE
  JOIN SW_WORKPRICES P ON P.WORKID=decode(d.DOC_TYPE,1,1944,2,1945,3,1946,4,1947,5,1948,6,1949,7,1950,8,1951,9,1952,10,1953,11,1954,12,1955,13,1956,14,1957,15,1958,16,1959,17,1960) 
            AND P.YEAR = ST.YEAR AND P.SEMESTER=ST.SEMESTER
  where s.STATUS_CODE=3
  GROUP by ST.YEAR, ST.SEMESTER, SR.PERSONID, d.DOC_TYPE;
```

Answer (score 1):

The column list for the view definition and the first branch of the union in your query have 16 items.

The other branches like

```
  UNION ALL   
  SELECT ST.YEAR, ST.SEMESTER, SR.PERSONID, 14, 482, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, sum(DECODE(P.ITEMS,0,1,1/P.ITEMS)*P.PRICE), 
            sum(DECODE(P.ITEMS,0,1,1/P.ITEMS)*P.PRICE), sum(DECODE(P.ITEMS,0,1,1/P.ITEMS)*P.PRICE), 0, 0
  FROM DOP_LESSONS L 
  ...
```

only have 15. You've added the `rating3` column so you need a corresponding calculation or dummy value in the same place - i.e. add an expression before the `, 0, 0` on all the other branches.

That might not be the only issue, of course. You can query the `user_errors` or `all_errors` views to see the actual problem, filtering on your view name.

Answer (score 0):

Query is too complex to analyze it (especially as we don't have your tables), so:

- when I copied your code into TOAD, it complained that **the number of items in the alias-list and query does not match**

  - that can - possibly - be easily fixed by removing column list from the first line and keep only

    ```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "EDUC"."PF_RATING" AS
    ```

    presuming that you used aliases throughout the code. If so, Oracle will automatically use these aliases while creating the view
- if that's not "it", then run the `SELECT` statement alone. If it is correctly written, good - view should then be created with no problems. If not, fix errors first. As I said, I can't tell what might be wrong without additional information